# bcftools consensus not working when using -H flag

Tags: vcf, vcftools

Sorry, I have been trying to work this out desparately all day. [Biostars couldn't find any answer](https://www.biostars.org/p/315458/#315686) so I am cross posting here.

I am trying to get both the left and right reference genome using a sample name in phase VCF file.

This works:

```
bcftools consensus -f lyrata_chr01-short.fasta phasedVCF-short.vcf.gz -s ms01e -H 1 > ms01e-left.fa
```

When I am trying to make the new Ref Sequence by imputing genotype from the right haplotype, this doesn't work.

```
bcftools consensus -f lyrata_chr01-short.fasta phasedVCF-short.vcf.gz -s ms01e -H 2 > ms01e-right.fa
Broken VCF, too few alts at 1:141
```

**What is the issue ?**

Here is my VCF data:

```
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  MA605   MA611   MA622   MA625   MA629   Ncm8    Sp154   Sp164   Sp21    Sp3 Sp76    SpNor33 ms01e   ms02g   ms03g   ms04h
1   141 .   C   T   .   .   .   GT:PG:PG_al:PI  .   .   .   0|1:0|1:C|T:10763   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
1   3697    .   T   C   .   .   .   GT:PG:PG_al:PI  .   0|0:0|0:T|T:11398   .   0|1:0|1:T|C:8039    0|1:0|1:T|C:8202    0|1:0|1:T|C:4616    0|1:0|1:T|C:3938    .   0|1:0|1:T|C:5102    .   .   0|1:0|1:T|C:17340   1|0:1|0:C|T:1   .   .   .
```

The `GT` field is empty at `POS 141` for `SAMPLE ms01e`, but in that situation it should by default pick a `REF` allele. Isn't it? 
And, it only is the problem when doing `-H 2` not `-H 1`.

**Update**: I have been trying to fix this issue by playing with `-i and -e` using the BCFtools manual. But, still cannot find the fix.

Comment: I don't know much about VCF but the first row seems to have less fields than the second. Is this normal/accepted format ? Also did you try the latest version (as [per](https://www.biostars.org/p/315458/#315750) ) ?